# CodeMirror: external search dialog

Tags: codemirror

I am building a small service based on CodeMirror where I would like to have the search box appear as a div rather than a popup as in the CodeMirror example. Further I would like to initiate the "search next" and "search previous" functions through clicks as well as via keyboard.

I am not sure how to do this, could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own `CodeMirror.prototype.openDialog` method that shows the dialog the way you want (just conform to [the interface](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_dialog)). And you can run `editor.execCommand("findNext")` (or `"findPrev"`) from a button's click handler to search next/previous.

Comment: Hi Maijn, I managed to get the findNext and findPrev, but I did not manage to get the other working. What I'm trying to do is have the search dialog appear after a click and then initiating the search itself on clicking a button. Can you help me please?